# Scraping table in python with help of beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape 3 tables from this url `https://ens.dk/sites/ens.dk/files/OlieGas/mp202112ofu.htm`

table 1 : oil production
table 2 : gas production
table 3 : water production

doesnt need to include the charts just 3 tables

I have wrote code to scrape links however not sure how to scrape table from links

```
import io
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs, SoupStrainer
import re


url = "https://ens.dk/en/our-services/oil-and-gas-related-data/monthly-and-yearly-production"

first_page = requests.get(url)

soup = bs(first_page.content)

def pasrse_page(link):
    print(link)
    df = pd.read_html(link, skiprows=1, headers=1)
    return df

def get_gas_links():
    glinks=[]
    gas_links = soup.find('table').find_all('a')
    for i in gas_links:
        extracted_link = i['href']
        #you can validate the extracted link however you want
        glinks.append("https://ens.dk/" + extracted_link)

    return glinks

get_gas_links()
```

output list of links : [list of links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksfJK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `pandas` to get the table data and then massage it to your liking.

Here's how:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0",
}

page = requests.get("https://ens.dk/sites/ens.dk/files/OlieGas/mp202112ofu.htm", headers=headers).text
df = pd.concat(pd.read_html(page, flavor="lxml"))
df.to_csv("oil_tables.csv", index=False)
```

This will get you a `.csv` file that looks like this:

[image]